# NSString containing parentheses ()

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Just start learning obj c and iOS and NSstring drive me crazy,

```
NSString *iTunesSongURL;
```

value of iTunesSongURL is [image]

I just want to join two strings

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",  iTunesSongURL, @"&at=sdsdgsd"]);
```

But result is like

```
(
    "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/im-yours/id277635758?i=277635828&uo=4"
)&at=sdsdgsd
```

But I want the result like

```
    "https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/im-yours
/id277635758?i=277635828&uo=4&at=sdsdgsd"
```

I spend lot of time on it but can't figure out small things. Any help

Comment: @downvoter: Why down vote? No solutions works for me given bellow

Comment: as I checked your debugger and come to know that iTunesSongURL is NSArray. So let me edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
NSString *iTunesSongURLString = iTunesSongURL.firstObject

NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&at=sdsdgsd",  iTunesSongURLString]);
```

Explanation:-
%@ means dynamic value is passing to strig. In your case, `iTunesSongURL` is the only dynamic string. `&at=sdsdgsd` is static string so put it directly in double quotes.

Comment: not compiled, .firstObject is not valid for NSString

Comment: Declare iTunesSongURL as NSArray

Comment: yes working, Thanks. Manny question in my mind but will study later more about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your object `iTunesSongURL` is an array. You should write it as below

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",  [iTunesSongURL objectAtIndex:0], @"&at=sdsdgsd"]);
```

Comment: I declared `iTunesSongURL` as NSString, How it became array?

Comment: As you show in the image in the log 'iTunesSongURL' is NSArray, so Chetan's answer should work if it's NSArray

Comment: As @Pyro said, the image you uploaded shows  'iTunesSongURL' as an array.

Answer (score 0):

First u need to declare :

```
NSArray *iTunesSongURL;
```

retrieve the response in the array and use

```
 NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&at=sdsdgsd",[iTunesSongURL objectAtIndex:0]]);
```

Comment: you forgot to add  ]  after 0 .          objectAtIndex:0]]);